# run 2 scripts in same DAG with different schedule

Tags: airflow

Let's say you have 2 scripts: Daily_summary.py and Weekly_summary.py.
You could create 2 separate DAGs with daily and weekly schedules, but is it possible to solve this with 1 DAG?

I've tried a daily schedule, and simply putting this at the bottom (simplified):

```
if datetime.today().strftime('%A') == 'Sunday':  
     SSHOperator(run weekly_summary.py)
```

But problem is that if it is still running on Sunday at midnight, airflow will terminate this task since the Operator no longer exists on Monday.

If I could somehow get the execution day's day-of-the-week, that would solve it, but with Jinja templating '{{ds}}' it is not actually a text of 'yyyy-mm-dd', so cannot change it to date with datetime package. It only becomes date format somehow AFTER the airflow script gets executed

Answer (score 1):

You shoudl dynamically generate two DAGs. But you can reuse the same code for that. This is the power of airflow - this is Python code, so you can easily use the same code to generate same DAG "structure" but with two diferent dag ids, and two different schedules.

See this nice article from Astronomer with some examples: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags

Comment: thanks. Seems accomplishing original question is impossible, but this is very useful!